# Why is the verb in first position here? is there something omitted?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammar-identification

> Sie besorgen sich Ihre Ausrüstung, **nehme** ich an?

I assume it's not the kind of literal question "Do i assume?". So what's going on, is there something omitted before the verb? THX

Comment: "Ich nehme an, Sie besorgen sich ihre Ausrüstung". The second part is called a "Verbzweitnebensatz". It is NOT a main clause, but a secondary clause that looks like a main clause. You encounter them in a few places. By "main clause" I mean typical declarative ones with verb at second position.

Comment: are these Verbzweitnebensätze only dass-omitted clauses?

Comment: @srmuil I don't know much about them, and they are a bit complicated, but it is not an omission, simply because the verbs are in different positions.

Comment: well, that's what Hammer's German Grammar calls them at 17.2.1(b) - "The conjunction dass can sometimes be omitted, and the subordinate clause then has the order of a main clause..."

Comment: @srmuil Okay, that is not how I understand "omission", I understand omission as leaving out e.g. "that" in a "that"-clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *to presume.*

> Doctor Livingstone, I presume?

> Doktor Livingstone, nehme ich an?

---

The part

> Sie besorgen sich Ihre Ausrüstung, …

is a **dependent clause** and the object of *annehmen*. This is set as the topic of the second (the actual) main clause.

Yep. In German, main clauses can be used as dependent clauses.

> Ich nehme an, dass Sie sich sich Ihre Ausrüstung besorgen.

> Ich nehme an, Sie besorgen sich Ihre Ausrüstung.

The meaning is the same. The nice part of this is that you can specify a topic in the "dependent main" clause:

> Ich nehme an, Ihre Ausrüstung besorgen Sie sich.

Oh, and yes, it may still be the topic of the outer clause.

> Ihre Ausrüstung besorgen Sie sich, nehme ich an.

Comment: that's sooooo interesting.... well I'm glad I didn't assume it was just an omission as I didn't know about this fact.

Comment: In general, this feature is limited to assumptions and hearsay. You may either use a verb as *annehmen*, *glauben*, *scheinen*, *heißen* etc and/or put the "dependent main" clause in Konjunktiv I mood.

Comment: Are you saying this is a dass omitted clause? I know that if you use a noun clause (so a dass clause) as the subject of a verb the verb has to have third person singular endings. Is it not the case with dass omitted clauses?

Comment: With *annehmen*, the thing you presume is its accusative object. With *heißen* it is its predicative. I've yet to find a verb that allows this which may take a subject clause.

Comment: E.g. *Ihre Ausrüstung besorgen Sie sich selbst, hieß die Anweisung gestern noch.*

Comment: ok let me see if I understood correctly what you said is happening: with annehmen you can't have a clause as a subject (makes sense to me), and the first clause in the current example is in the first position through a change of topic? that's all what's going on here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146740/discussion-between-janka-and-srmuiel).

Comment: "main clauses can be used as dependent clauses" is at least inaccurate. Rather, dependent clauses can have the same word order as main clauses.

Comment: What's wrong with assume? "Doctor Livingstone, I assume?"

Answer (score 0):

The verb is not in first position. It is in second position.

The subclause "Sie besorgen sich Ihre Ausrüstung" is the first part of the sentence. It is the object of the verb *nehme .. an*, therefore it is called an *Objektsatz* in German.

Comment: Objektsätze sind Nebensätze

Comment: Ich habe nichts anderes behauptet.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to think about these types of sentences is to view the final phrase with the verb in first position as parenthetical.

> Sie besorgen sich Ihre Ausrüstung (nehme ich an)?
> Sie besorgen sich (nehme ich an) Ihre Ausrüstung?
> Sie (nehme ich an) besorgen sich Ihre Ausrüstung?